# List all files except a few in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I have a directory of files named as

> 1_1.xyt, 1_2.xyt,..., 2_1.xyt,.....

I want to list all files except the one that starts with 1_* in linux.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you can use `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(1_*)
```

Where the `!(wildcard)` expands to all the files that don't match the wildcard.